# pandas set partial data and get SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, chained-assignment

I tried to set the partial data to -1, but I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

I tried to find StackOverflow, but lots of answers use loc to solved.

The data comes from Kaggle Titanic.

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
y = train[["Survived"]]
y.loc[y["Survived"]  == 0,"Survived"] = -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic appears confused. Try this instead:

```
train.loc[train["Survived"]  == 0,"Survived"] = -1
```

There is no need to set `y = train[['Survived']]` and this is what is causing your warning.

You can read about how to use `.loc` accessor in the Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: But I still don't know why y = train[['Survived']] cause this bug.
It is a DataFrame and isn't a copy.
Why can't I use loc on y ?

Comment: This is a *warning*. It may or may not work, but it's not good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I think I know why the warning happened.